# Creating eclipse war file from command line

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, war

I have a web project in eclipse, and I need to get a war file from it. Usually I right-click the project, go to Export and click `WAR file`.

But I need to find a way to do this from the command line. I tried going to the classes directory where eclipse outputs the `.class` files and I ran this command:

```
jar -cvf project_name.war *
```

I got the file but it's different from the one eclipse outputs. This one is about 100kb, eclipse outputs more than 2000kb.

What is the right command I can use to get the same `war` file as from eclipse?

Comment: just check what is in war file created by eclipse and create a script that will compile classes and package everything in the same way.

Comment: For the newbs:.war files (and jar files) have the same format as .zip files. If you're on Windows you can just add ".zip" to the end of the filename and double-click it to open it.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to look at Ant, or similar build process, as you're going to need to put all your classes and dependencies in the JAR, build the manifest and add the web XML file also into WEB-INF. It can be done with multiple calls to jar.exe using the -u parameter also, if you wish, but Ant is far better at handling changes. It conditionally compiles, builds, etc, only as required.

```
jar cf WebApp.war . (or whatever classes/directories you wish to include)
jar uf, etc...
jar uf, etc...
```

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-a-war-file-using-the-jar-command.html

http://ant.apache.org/

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html